# Extract text from webpage using either Python or Applescript

Tags: python, url, text, applescript, extract

So I've constructed an Applescript that inputs information into a website.  What I am now trying to figure out is a way to extract a "redirected URL" from the pages contents to store in a python shell string [Automator OSX].

Basically, I know how to scan html to find a body of text in Python if I know the URL.  In these cases, I do not know the URL but the URL is on the webpage

I've thought of 2 different approaches:

**1) Is there a way to extract text information from an open browser document in Applescript**?  If it was Python, then I would just use regex to search for what I need but I don't know how to do this in Applescript.

If not, then

2) Is there a way to obtain the URL through Python of an open browser document? If so, then I would be able to use urllib to get the information I need.

I'm looking to extract the URL following:

"As soon as calculations are done, you can access your results here: "

***Note, the URL in the browser is the same as this URL, but only after the data has been processed.  The time varies for each analysis so that is why I don't want to get the URL straight from the toolbar area.  However, this link pops up instantaneously

[image]

The address for the webpage is:

### [http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/cgi-bin/RNAfold.cgi?P](http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/cgi-bin/RNAfold.cgi?P%22)

Updated part of the question

3)
If using Safari.app  is there a way to click the "proceed" submit button using Applescript

Comment: Added a new update that get the url directly without iteration.

Comment: I have update your question and supplied an answer to part 3 of your question in my answer as an update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using safari.

And if the link is always the same index when counting the links.

i.e link number 4.

You could try:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set thelink to do JavaScript "document.links[4].href " in document 1
end tell
```

Which will return the links url.

----------UPDATE

A second way is return the link that contains "RNAfold/"

```
tell application "Safari" to set thelinkCount to do JavaScript "document.links.length " in document 1
set theUrl to ""
repeat with i from 1 to thelinkCount
    tell application "Safari" to set this_link to (do JavaScript "document.links[" & i & "].href" in document 1) as string
    if this_link contains "RNAfold/" then
        set theUrl to this_link
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

log theUrl
```

---

UPDATE 2

This goes directly to the innerHTML of the link without iteration and returns the url string

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1 to set theUrl to (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].getElementsByTagName('b')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').item(0).innerHTML; ")
 end tell
```

---

UPDATE 3

Added after new part to question.

To click the "proceed" submit button.
You get its class name and use some more javascript to click ii

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('proceed')[0].click()" in document 1
```

---

**Full example**

```
set theUrl to ""

tell application "Safari"

    tell document 1

        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('proceed')[0].click()"
        delay 1
        set timeoutCounter to 0
        repeat until (do JavaScript "document.readyState") is "complete"
            set timeoutCounter to timeoutCounter + 1

            delay 0.5
            if timeoutCounter is greater than 50 then
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        set theUrl to (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].getElementsByTagName('b')[0].getElementsByTagName('a').item(0).innerHTML; ")

    end tell
end tell
log theUrl
```

Comment: I have added a full example

Comment: I find a lot of the JS documentation (e.g. on MDN) to be written for someone who isn't me. I've had a pesky 'flyer' problem that I've had to workaround using UI elements scripting, which I loathe. This helped me put something quick and simple together.

Answer (score 1):

No error correction at all here, but you could try, with Safari, something like:

```
tell application "Safari" to set s to source of document 1

set o1 to offset of "results here: <a href" in s
set o2 to offset of "</a></b><br><br>" in s

text (o1 + 23) thru (o2 - 1) of s
```

I saw the url, went to the site, used a sample RNA sequence, used the cgi, got to the page and ran this script, and it extracted the url. But (as I'm sure you know), that page auto-directs to another page within several seconds.

[edit:] or, getting the refresh meta tag from the top of the page:

```
tell application "Safari" to set s to source of document 1

set topRefreshMetaTagPar to paragraph 6 of s

text 45 thru -3 of topRefreshMetaTagPar
```

Comment: is there a reason this doesn't work for firefox? i use a series of tab key codes that only work in firefox and not in safari.  the set s to source of dumenet 1 doesn't work in firefox for some weird reason

Comment: You need to read the applescript library for Firefox to see what the equivalent syntax is.

Comment: hmm saying that. Firefox does not seem to have any of it's own suites. So you may be out of luck using it with applescript

Comment: oh i see what you mean. is there a way to "click" the Proceed button in Safari? Before, I was pressing tab a bunch of times until it got to the Proceed button but that was in Firefox